# If $\sum\sqrt{f(n)}$ converges then $\sum f'(n)$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $f$ be a positive nondecreasing differentiable function s.t. $\lim f(n)$ is $\infty$.
>
> Prove or disprove the following statements:
>
> 1. If $\sum1/\sqrt{f(n)}$ converges then $\sum1/ f'(n)$ converges.
> 2. If $\sum1/ f'(n)$  converges then $\sum1/\sqrt{f(n)}$ converges.

In order to prove the first statement I wanted to show $\ f'(n) \le \sqrt{f(n)}$, But im not sure this is true at all.

The second statement seems incorrect and i've already found a counterexample.

Any hints with the first statement would be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint :** For the first statement, consider a nondecreasing function $g$ such that for every integer $n \geq 1$, $g(n)=n^4$ and $g'(n)=n^8$ (it is easy to see, at least graphically, that such a function exists).

Comment: Also it may help to completely forget about $g$ - in fact the conditions of the problem are (more or less) equivalent with saying that $f$ is differentiable, positive and nonincreasing. So let's just tweak $f$. First make it $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^4}$ so that $\sum \sqrt{f(n)}$ converges. Then this function will have a small derivative/tangent slope at integer points - make it larger *just* around those points. (You may want to make $f$ go down rapidly around integer points and then stagnate/stay constant otherwise.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop My bad, I had a typo. Just editted.

Comment: @idoeido: But that idea still works: You can make $f'(n)$ arbitrarily small at all integers while $\sum1/\sqrt{f(n)}$ is still convergent.